# Splitting a string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of strings that look like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>;
list.add("AAPL7131221P00590000");
list.add("AAPL7131206C00595000");
list.add("AAPL7131213P00600000");
```

I would like to remove the date that is between `AAPL7` and the next letter which is either `C` or `P`, and then add it to a new list. How do I use regex to get: `131221`, `131206`, or `131212` so I can populate a new list?

Comment: Will it always be AAPL7?

Comment: It could be AAPL, GOOG, GOOG7, etc.  but I will know what the start of the string looks like.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to C#, but I do it that way in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex for this one, you can just use `Substring`, assuming that all your inputs will be the same number of characters.

```
var startingString = "AAPL7"; // holds whatever the starting string is
var input = "AAPL7131221P00590000";

var outputDate = input.Substring(startingString.Length, 6);
```

So if you wanted to make this a one-liner for making a collection:

```
List<string> allDates = yourInputValues
    .Select(x => x.Substring(startingString.Length, 6))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for. I though the only way was to use regex, so thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code snippet...

```
string startPattern = "AAPL7"; // GOOGL, GOOG, etc
List<string> newlist = list
    .Select(n => Regex.Match(n, string.Format(@"(?<=^{0})\d+", startPattern)).Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Only downside to this approach is you would have to change the pattern every time the starting value changed.

Comment: well...We can always introduce a variable where we need in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Regex regex = new Regex("(\\w{5})(\\d*)(\\w*)");
        Regex regex = new Regex("(\\w*)(\\d{6})([PC])(\\d*)");
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("AAPL7131221P00590000");
        list.Add("AAPL7131206C00595000");
        list.Add("AAPL7131213P00600000");
        List<string> extracted = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in list)
        {
            extracted.Add(regex.Split(item)[2]);
        }
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I just add something that may help in case you have the different date length (i.e. 14131 for 31st, January 2014)

```
string startpart = "AAPL7"; // or whatever
string mainstring = "AAPL714231P00590000"; // or any other input

mainstring = mainstring.Substring(startpart.Length); //this will through away startpart

int index;
if (mainstring.IndexOf("P") >= 0) index = mainstring.IndexOf("P"); //if there is no "P" it gives -1
else index = mainstring.IndexOf("C");

string date = mainstring.Substring(0,index);
```

i guess it is a safe approach to handle wider cases